# print something dynamically to replace the old printed thing and so on

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to do something that seems quite simple, but haven't achieved to do it yet.

Basically, I just want to print something on the exact same line so that this new printed thing replace the old printed thing.

Let's take this piece of code of example:

```
import time

for i in range (0, 20):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

I want the second output ("2") to replace the first one ("1"), then the third output ("3") to replace the second one, and so one.

I've seen some old answers on the Internet, that say there's the "flush" parameter which I can add my print statement. So I tried:

```
import time

for i in range (0, 20):
    print(i, flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Doesn't really change anything.

- I'm on Mac OS X if that implies anything -

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Use `stdout`

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
```

**Update**

```
for i in range(10):
    print("\r%d" % i, end="")
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: are you sure? i tested in Mac only.

Comment: It's working, thanks! I tried this code PyCharm, and it does exactly what I was looking for. It just doesn't work in IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using terminal to run the program then :

```
for i in range(10):
    stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
```

but if you are running the program with idle then it wont work !

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you use python 3, use `'\r'` to go to beginning of line and `end=""` to stay on the same line. Combined they give the effect you are looking for.

For example:

```
import time

print("\r[]", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r  []", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r    []", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r      []", end="")
time.sleep(1)
print("\r        []", end="")
```

Comment: @Michael Try this one, I just tested it on my machine and it worked.